# dont work the sql command for view the listiner status please help me?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, storage, local-storage, decorator

i read the document of oracle database XE and then:
for view the listiner status work with command:

To view listener status:

1. Do one of the following:

   - On Linux: Start a terminal session and log in to the Oracle Database XE host
     computer with the oracle user account.
   - On Windows: Log in to the Oracle Database XE host computer as the user who
     installed Oracle Database XE, and then open a command window.
2. On Linux, ensure that environment variables are set according to the instructions
   in "Setting Environment Variables on the Linux Platform" on page 3-5.
3. Enter the following command: `LSNRCTL STATUS`

and then i try to do the work in my oracle,the command dont work:

my command is in sql commadnd prompt :

```
CONNECT USERNAME/PASSWORD AS SYSDBA;
LSNRCTL STATUS;
```

The top query doesn't work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LSNRCTL STATUS` is ***not*** a SQL statement. `LSNRCTL` is a program installed together with Oracle and the Listener. You therefor need to run it in a regular command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

`lsnrctl status`must be run from the command line interface (CLI), not from within SQL*Plus